# How to run release code instead of debug?

Tags: release, icloud, visionos

I have an app which uses iCloud on VisionOS and it correctly accesses the debug iCloud folders but cannot see my real iCloud folder.

I have logged into iCloud on the sim and can open the folder from the VisionOS directly and see my iCloud files.

If I set the scheme to Release, it makes no difference.

Comment: Have. you punished the schema?

Comment: Yes. I've done a bit more research and this seems to be related to iCloud not the Release builds.

Comment: Also, switching back and forth between release and debug erased all the files in the simulator's test folders. In my case all files below TESTING (below) were erased;

/Users/development/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C22A0DD-3286-4BED-8759-795092C1FFBD/data/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~cmsmedicalsystems~iamTheCuratorV/TESTING